# How to correct the pose during navigation？

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 16.04.I have a real robot with lidar, ultrasound and camera now . And i am using move_ base package for navigation. The robot is a four-wheel drive robot（with Mecanum wheels）. Because the both sides of the robot is different(for example, one side is a blanket and the other side is a metal floor)，which cause the friction coefficient of the tires on both sides of the robot is different, there will be deviation during navigation so the robot can't walk in a straight line. How to make the robot walk in a straight line during navigation ?Can it be done？
Thank you！

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374261/how-to-correct-the-pose-during-navigation%EF%BC%9F/) by [Rikyuugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72137/rikyuugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, `move_base` operates as kind of a feedback control loop.  When the local planner notices your robot deviating from the global plan, it should take corrective action, approximately following a straight line overall.  You may be able to tune some parameters to get it to do a better job, though.  Feel free to clarify if this doesn't quite answer your question.

If you want general tuning help, [Zheng's tuning guide](https://kaiyuzheng.me/documents/navguide.pdf) is a good place to start.  If you have a more specific problem/behavior, you can always post another question.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rikyuugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72137/rikyuugo/) on 2021-03-19**:
Sorry for the late reply. Thanks a lot！ This guide is exactly what I need. I will try it.   :)
In fact, the main function of my robot is to patrol in the narrow computer room (at the same time, the ground on both sides of the robot is different). Therefore, the robot must keep a straight line in the whole navigation process.
I subscribed to ultrasonic and create a function to detect the ultrasonic data on one side of the robot (if the difference is too large, I return a PARREL = false to tell the robot that it is not a straight line). Then I create another function and subscribe to another topic (self_inserted_waypoint_goals) to receive navigation goal. However, when I send the target goal and the robot starts to move, the robot can no longer accept PARREL in the process of walking to the target(the robot will not continue to return PARREL=false or PARREL=true） until it reaches the target point.

**Comment by [Rikyuugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72137/rikyuugo/) on 2021-03-19**:
If I still can't solve this, I will create a new question and attach the picture (I don't have enough points(>5 points) now).Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-19**:
No problem! Feel free to tag me if you do make a new question.  I gave you some karma, so you should be able to post pictures.

**Comment by [Rikyuugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72137/rikyuugo/) on 2021-03-25**:
Thanks again for tryan's reply. I've solved this problem by tuning some parameters.At the same time,I was subscribing to ultrasonic data to determine parallelism and sending the angular velocity to the /cmd_vel.